# How do I prove if $\lim a_{2n}=L$ and $\lim a_{2n+1}=L$ then $a_n$ converges and $\lim a_n =L$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

This seems obvious as its just saying that if the sequence has $L$ for limit when $n$ is odd and even then the sequence has $L$ for its limit. Yet, I am not quite sure how to prove this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$. There are $N_1, N_2$ such that for all even $n>N_1$, $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ and for all odd $n>N_2$, $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$. Let $N= \max \{N_1, N_2 \}$. Then if $n>N$ it is either even or odd, and either way $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$.

Comment: The standard proof, probably answered here lot of times.

Comment: Thanks, sorry i am new to this site :)

Comment: However, how come you have to choose N1 and N2, and cannot just go with one N?

Comment: @ChaowWu What do you mean? How would you do that?

Comment: I mean why do you say that there is N1 and N2, cant you say: for ϵ>0 there is N such that for all even n> N, |an−L| < ϵ and |an−L|<ϵ  for all odd n > N. Why do you need to find the max of N1 and N2? sorry if this is trivial

Comment: @ChaowWu What you wrote is true, but you need to justify it. How do you know that $N$ works for both even and odd terms?

Comment: Oh, I see, so finding the max for N1 and N2 is the justification then, thank you very much for your help